# How to process Text Qualifier delimited file in scala

Tags: java, regex, scala

I have a lot of delimited files with Text Qualifier (every column start and end has double quote). Delimited is not consistent i.e. there can be any delimited like comma(,), Pipe (|), ~, tab (\t).

I need to read this file with text (single column) and then check no of delimiters by considering Text Qualifier. If any record has less or more columns than defined that record should be rejected and loaded to different path.

Below is test data with 3 columns ID, Name and DESC. DESC column has extra delimiter.

> "ID","Name","DESC" 
>   "1" , "ABC", "A,B C" 
>   "2" , "XYZ" , "ABC is bother" 
>   "3" , "YYZ" , ""
>   4 , "XAA" , "sf,sd 
>   sdfsf"

**Last record splitted into two records due new line char in desc field**

Below is the code I tried to handle but not able to handle correctly.

```
val SourceFileDF = spark.read.text(InputFilePath)
SourceFile = SourceFile.filter("value != ''") // Removing empty records while reading
val aCnt = coalesce(length(regexp_replace($"value","[^,]", "")), lit(0)) //to count no of delimiters
val Delimitercount = SourceFileDF.withColumn("a_cnt", aCnt)
var invalidrecords= Delimitercount
                    .filter(col("a_cnt")
                    .!==(NoOfDelimiters)).toDF()
val GoodRecordsDF = Delimitercount
                .filter(col("a_cnt")
                .equalTo(NoOfDelimiters)).drop("a_cnt")
```

With above code I am able to reject all the records which has less or more delimiters but not able to ignore if delimiter is with in text qualifier.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you know the column number is 3, you could use something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/u9Jnt9/1) (or [this one](https://regex101.com/r/u9Jnt9/2)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew -- To show my scenario I had explained with test data of 3 columns. There can be multiple columns having description and we don`t  know description fields position with delimiter  with in double quotes

Comment: Yeah, but I also showed an example pattern. Once you know the number of columns, you may build the pattern dynamically by adding more `\s*(?:,\s*)?("(?:""|[^"])*"|\d+)` parts to the end of the pattern. If the number of columns may differ within one table, that is more difficult since you will have to add them as optional parts, `(?:\s*(?:,\s*)?("(?:""|[^"])*"|\d+))?` and you will have to account for that in code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew -- Can we replace delimiter between double quotes using replace. Can you give regex for that if you know

Comment: That does not seem what you ask about, but I guess you want to remove `,`  and perhaps other chars inside double quotes. I guess you will have to use something like https://ideone.com/ooUC9Z

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, my requirement is achived

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a closure with `replaceAllIn` to remove any chars you want inside a match:

```
var y = """4 , "XAA" , "sf,sd\nsdfsf""""
val pattern = """"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"""".r
y = pattern replaceAllIn (y, m => m.group(0).replaceAll("[,\n]", ""))
print(y) // => 4 , "XAA" , "sfsdnsdfsf"
```

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/ooUC9Z).

**Details**

- `"` - matches a `"`
- `[^"]*` - any 0+ chars other than `"`
- `(?:""[^"]*)*` - matches 0 or more sequences of `""` and then 0+ chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"`.

The code finds all non-overlapping matches of the above pattern in `y` and upon finding a match (`m`) the `,` and newlines (LF) are removed from the match value (with `m.group(0).replaceAll("[,\n]", "")`, where `m.group(0)` is the match value and `[,\n]` matches either `,` or a newline).